# Magento2 Cron not running

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

My cron file code as follows.crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="My\Catalog\Cron\CheckCatalogMrp" method="execute" name="My_catalog_cron">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Cron is not running and when i run the command `php bin/magento cron:run` It is giving output as "Ran Jobs by Schedule"

But my magento.cron.log file have this error. How can i resolve this error?

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

My execute method as follows.

```
public function execute()
    {  
       /* $state = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');*/
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
       /* $directory = 'PosMrp';
        if(!is_dir(BP.'var/log/'.$directory)) {
            mkdir(BP.'var/log/'.$directory,0777,true);
        } */

        $log_file = 'return_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log';
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/'.$log_file);
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);        
        $today1 = date("m/d/Y H:i:s");
          $logger->info($today1.' - today');

         //$cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+5 hour +30 minutes',strtotime($today1)));
        $barcodes = array();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('neq' => 'wallet_product'));
        $collection->setPageSize(10);
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $barcodes[] = "".$product->getSku()."";             
        }
        $store_id = 14567;
        $call_url = 'http://myesydata.com';
        $request_url = $call_url.'/online/getMrp'; 

        $data = array(
            'store_id' => $store_id,
            'barcodes' =>  $barcodes
        );

        $post = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $response = curl_exec($post);
        curl_close($post);
        $result = json_decode($response, true); 
        if($result['success'] == 1){
            if($result['data']){
                foreach ($result['data'] as $key => $value) {                   
                    $product_rep =  $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($key);
                    if($product_rep){
                        if($product_rep->getPrice()  != $value && $value != 0){
                            $product_rep->setPrice($value);
                            if($product_rep->save()){
                                 $logger->info($key.' - Price Updated');
                            }else{
                                $logger->info($key.' - Price Update Failed');
                            }
                        }else{
                            $logger->info($key.' - Product Not Found');

                        }
                    }else{
                        $logger->info($key.' - Product Price Same as Previous----ECOM PRICE----'.$product_rep->getPrice().'POS PRICE---'.$value);
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
        $logger->info('Status'.json_encode($result));
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: execute method can you check that one

Comment: please upload code of this file CheckCatalogMrp in question

Comment: added my execute function as well. plz check once

Comment: please upload full of code not only execute method

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

> etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="my_catalog_cron" instance="My\Catalog\Cron\Checkcatalogmrp" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 1 * * *</schedule>
        </job>                           
    </group>
</config>
```

> My\Catalog\Cron\Checkcatalogmrp.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Catalog\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Checkcatalogmrp {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute() {

        //Write your code here



    }

}
```